# Не могу отправить форму в MongoDB

Tags: php, сервер, mongodb, форма, http-status-code-500

Пытаюсь отправить простую форму на MongoDB.
Есть страница "log_in_page.html", "index.php".
Каждый раз делая submit, получаю error 500.
В интернете нашлось несколько вариантов, все были применены, но проблему это не решило.
А именно:

- изменены права доступа .html и .php :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216761/the-localhost-page-isn-t-working-localhost-is-currently-unable-to-handle-this-re
- добавлен драйвер: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.pecl.php

Форма:

```
<form method='POST' action='index.php'>
 <input type="email" name="email">Email</input>
 <input type="password" name="password">Password</input>
 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Файл php (далее **user** - это БД и **user_data** - это коллекция):

```
<?php
$client = new MongoDB\Client(
    'mongodb+srv://user_access:мой_пароль@кластер.mjvzyla.mongodb.net/? 
     retryWrites=true&w=majority'
);
$userCollection = $client->user->user_data;
$insertOneResult = $userCollection->insertOne([
   'email' => $_POST['email'],
   'password' => $_POST['password'],
]);
?>
```

Далее ошибка **Internal Server Error**.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0):

Порылась в логах, была ошибка с сертификатами:
**TLS handshake failed: certificate verify failed (20): unable to get local issuer certificate calling hello on...**

Решение - добавить **&tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=true**

```
$client = new MongoDB\Client(
    'mongodb+srv://user_access:мой_пароль@кластер.mjvzyla.mongodb.net/? 
     retryWrites=true&w=majority&tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=true'
);
```